# How can I use/extend a new hard drive on ubuntu from my main ssd?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have my main(120gb SSD) drive with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on:

```
dev/sda1
```

I have another 3 TB hard drive which is formatted as ext4:

```
dev/sdb1
```

---

**What I would ideally like:**

I would like to "fuse" these two together so that they are treated as one drive and share the same home directory.

---

**What would also work:**

If I could easily navigate to the other drive on the command line and have it use all my other configs (git, vimrc, zshrc etc...)

---

If anyone could provide a set of commands/file edits that I could use to achieve either of these it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider moving the Home, `/home/` to the new hard disk. This is the easiest and highly recommended use of a second disk. Combining the 2 disks into a single logical volume means when any one disk fails you will lose everything. Moving some applications to the second disk (if I understand your second choice correctly) won't work.

Comment: @user68186 makes sense! Thanks you

Comment: Details on moving /home. [Move Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437 And alternative is to use a data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk
 With large drive like your, I like to have a small ESP & smaller full Ubuntu install without many extra apps, just for emergency boot.